# DISTINCT causing full table scan

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, distinct

I have a table in MySQL (5.5.31) which has about 20M rows. The following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mytable.name name FROM mytable 
LEFT JOIN mytable_c ON mytable_c.id_c = mytable.id
WHERE mytable.deleted = 0  ORDER BY mytable.date_modified DESC  LIMIT 0,21
```

is causing full table scan, with explain saying `type` is `ALL` and extra info is `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`. Explain results:

```
  id  select_type table           type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref         rows        Extra
  1   SIMPLE      mytable         ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        19001156    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
  1   SIMPLE      mytable_c       eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 108     mytable.id  1           Using index
```

Without the join explain looks like:

```
  id  select_type table           type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref         rows        Extra
  1   SIMPLE      mytable         index   NULL            mytablemod  9       NULL        21          Using where; Using temporary
```

`id_c` is the primary key for `mytable_c` and `mytable_c` does not have more than one row for every row in `mytable`. `date_modified` is indexed. But looks like MySQL does not understand that. If I remove the DISTINCT clause, then `explain` uses index and touches only 21 rows just as expected. If I remove the join it also does this.  Is there any way to make it work without the full table scan with the join? `explain` shows mysql knows it needs only one row from `mytable_c` and it is using the primary key, but still does full scan on `mytable`.

The reason DISTINCT is there that the query is generated by the ORM system in which there might be cases where multiple rows may be produced by JOINs, but the values of SELECT fields will always be unique (i.e. if JOIN is against multi-value link only fields that are the same in every joined row will be in SELECT).

Comment: You have an outer join on a table from which you select no columns. I don't get that.

Comment: @Strawberry this query is a bit simplified, but it *still* causing full table scan. That's the weird part - full table scan happens regardless of if I include fields from other tables or not.

Comment: Trying to answer this kind of question without seeing a) the explain and b) proper DDLs is just silly. (Not that I could do a much better job even with that information!)

Comment: @Strawberry I've added the explain result. I don't think table defs would matter a lot here - that happens with any type of fields but assume all fields are ints or varchars and and id, id_c and date_modified have indexes.

Comment: The implication being that none of those columns are PRIMARY?

Comment: @Strawberry `id` and `id_c` are the primary keys for respective tables.

Comment: If you arrive at a distinct list of names, how would you expect that list to be sorted by date? Date also needs to be in the select list, and you have other columns from the left joined table also. 'Select distinct' is a row operator i.e. it assesses every row **in total** to determine if the row is unique. So a wide row is more complex to assess than a narrow row.  If you were to show us the full query the causes of your performance issue might be easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

These are just generic comments, not mysql specific.

To find all the possible `name` values from `mytable` a full scan of either the table or an index needs to happen. Possible options:

- full table scan
- full index scan of an index starting with `deleted` (take advantage of the filter)
- full index scan of an index starting with `name` (only column of concern for output)

If there was an index on `deleted`, the server could find all the `deleted = 0` index entries and then look up the corresponding `name` value from the table.  But if `deleted` has low cardinality or the statistics aren't there to say differently, it could be more expensive to do the double reads of first the index then the corresponding data item. In that case, just scan the table.

If there was an index on `name`, an index scan could be sufficient, but then the table needs to be checked for the filter. Again frequent hopping from index to table.

The join columns also need to be considered in a similar manner.

If you forget about the join part and had a multi-part index on columns `name`, `deleted` then an index scan would probably happen.

Update

To me the `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` parts are a bit confusing. Of which `name` record is the `date_modified` to be used for sorting?  I think something like this would be a bit more clear:

```
SELECT mytable.name name --, MIN(mytable.date_modified)
  FROM mytable 
  LEFT JOIN mytable_c ON mytable_c.id_c = mytable.id
  WHERE mytable.deleted = 0
  GROUP BY mytable.name
  ORDER BY MIN(mytable.date_modified) DESC  LIMIT 0,21
```

Either way, once the `ORDER BY` comes into play, a full scan needs to be done to find the order.  Without the `ORDER BY`, the first 21 found could suffice.

Comment: deleted indeed tends to have very low selectivity, it has only two values (0 and 1) and for almost all rows it's 0. But it doesn't need to find all values for `name`, only 21 distinct ones, does it? Indeed, that is what happens without the join. But with the join, it does the full scan. Why?

Comment: @StasM Check this out regarding distinct and order by: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: But that is not what is happening - even with the order, full scan does not happen unless there is a join. It also should not be happening, as first 21 records from date_modified index fulfill the query (all names are distinct anyway) and no additional records are needed. Just noticed I forgot to mention explicitly - `date_modified` has an index.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try to move condition **mytable.deleted = 0** from WHERE to the JOIN ON ? You can also try FORCE INDEX (mytablemod)